# Why is parseInt not working in my code for project Euler #4 in java?

Tags: java, palindrome, parseint

I tried solving Project Euler #4 by converting my number to a string, reversing it, and converting it back into a number. The problem is commented out in my code.

```
package euler.proj;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //A palindromic number reads the same both ways.
        // The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
        //Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.
        int palindrome = 0;
        String reverse = "";
        for(int i = 100*100; i<= 999*999; i++){
            String pal = Integer.toString(i);
            for(int j = pal.length()-1; j >= 0; j--)
                reverse = reverse + pal.charAt(j);
            int k = Integer.parseInt(reverse);
            if (k == i)
                palindrome = k;
        }
        System.out.println("The largest palindromic product of two 3-digit numbers is " + palindrome);
    }
}
```

The program doesn't compile and IntelliJ gives these errors:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "000011000120001"

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:461)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:554)
at euler.proj.Main.main(Main.java from InputFileObject:15)
```

Comment: You don't need to convert to a string and back again to reverse it. You can do it with a loop and basic arithmetic operations.

Comment: Also, you don't need to search all numbers. Start at the top of the range, work downwards until you find the first (the largest) palindrome, and then stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number `000011000120001` (or `11.000.120.001` in different notation) does not fit in a 4 byte `Integer` (ranging from roughly -2.147.000.000 to 2.147.000.000). You can use `Long.parseLong(number)` for your application.

Edit: Additionally, you should move `String reverse = "";` within your for-loop, as you are currently appending all numbers that you are testing to it after each other, resulting in a gigantic number.

Comment: This is the reason for the exception. But you should be able to still use `int` values in your problem, since your maximum value should only be 999*999. Look closer at what happens with the `reverse` variable as it goes through each loop.

Comment: This did not seem to work.. It just gave an error with a bigger number. Is there any way that I could somehow dissect the loop and see what happens in each iteration?

Comment: That would mean that your algorithm is likely producing wrong results, exploding to higher and higher numbers. You can use `System.out.println(...)` to print in between results to manually verify them and find out where your code produces unexpected results.

Comment: I also do not understand why it gives such large numbers. As mentioned by @Lars, my maximum value should not exceed 999*999. Maybe there's something wrong with the way I solved the problem, but it seems fairly logical to me.

Comment: You should move `String reverse = "";` within your for loop. Right now, it's appending every number you check, rather than running your logic per number.

Comment: this is what happened when I tried System.out.println : 1
110001
11000120001
1100012000130001

Comment: Read my previous comment. I've also updated my answer.

Comment: Huzzah! I moved the string into my loop and it worked. Thank you so much Pieter12345! You have been a great help.